# multiple rows xml excel

Tags: xml, excel

I'm not good in coding but I need to convert an .xls to .xml. 
I did the XML mapping but Excel exports only the first row of the sheet. I've used suggestions seen in other posts here without success.

I think cause I have a different xml mapping, that has no "xsd" prefix at the beginning of the row. Here is my xml mapping: we.tl/K8fGVgD1XG

My code map is like this:

```
<Versione>5</Versione>
```

Instead the code map in the solved posts is like this:

```
<xsd:element name="Root">
```

In the solved posts is written to use the wordings "root" and "minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" but I don't know how to use them in my xml mapping.
Can you help me please?

Thank you

Chris

Comment: See [ask]. The idea is that everything necessary to answer your question is provided (usually as text) in the question itself so it is stand-alone. Tell us what problem you need to solve, what you have tried, and what results you get. This question will almost certainly need some sort of [mcve].

Comment: I've read it last week. I'm going ta add some code hoping could be useful